# Missing object faces on both .obj and .json formats three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Over the past few weeks, I've been having issues with loading models I've created in Blender. At first, I tried using .obj and .mtl files, but they were rendered with missing faces, even when `material.side` was set to `THREE.DoubleSide`. I converted the .obj files to .json files and rendered them that way, but the issue persisted.

[image]

You can see exactly where the missing faces are. When I upload to Clara.io, the model is rendered exactly how I want it to be:

[image]

In the past, I've triangulated the models to fix this issue, but it ended up distorting the models. Is there any known fix that won't distort my models?

For reference, here's the (simple) code I'm using to load the object:

```
var jloader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
jloader.load(
  'models/capsule/capsule.json',
  function ( geometry, materials ) {
      var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials );
      var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
      scene.add(object);
  }
);
```

Comment: A reasonable guess is your model has some polygonal faces with more than 4 sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing faces might be polygon instead of triangles or squares. Change them and you will be good to go.